# Survey web app that supports source code?

Tags: web-apps

I'm looking for something like SurveyMonkey, Typeform, or Google Forms that has two key features:

1. Branching logic.
2. Support for source code formatting (but not necessarily syntax highlighting).

For #2, it would be ideal to be able embed Github Gists. Next best would be Markdown support. At a minimum, I'd take the HTML `<pre>` tag.

If I can't try out the features #1 and #2 without paying, it's a no-go.

Happy to self-host if I need to.

Any thoughts?